# Is there a PayPal SDK that uses V2 of the REST API

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using the [Java SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK) for PayPal's REST API.

However, I notice that a lot of the SDK uses a version of the API that has been deprecated ([V1](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/) instead of [V2](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/)).

For example, the [sample docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/payments/#execute-payment) for executing a payment using the SDK use a `PaymentExecution` Object. As you can see from the API docs, this field is not relevant in the newer API (V2) and is only used in the older, deprecated V1.

Should I still use the SDK even though it uses the deprecated (V1) API? Is there some newer SDK I should be using instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: the new SDKs are over at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/setup-sdk/

Comment: Thanks, any ETA for an SDK for v2?

Comment: ^Updated my answer